# Can a flash application read data directly from USB port?

Tags: flash, usb

Can a flash application (SWF) access the serial data on a USB port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe :)
Flash alone cannot handle that.

As far as I can think of you can either:

1. Use a socket server (written in java,c#, etc.) that will access the serial data and send it to flash. You could use a [Binary Socket](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/Socket.html) or an [XML Socket](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/XMLSocket.html), depending on how you write the socket server. [WiiFlash](http://code.google.com/p/wiiflash/) uses a socket server and there are sources avaialable, might be a good start.
2. Make an AIR application and use the [Native Process API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) to another application that will send the data.

It might a bit off, since there are a bit outdated, but have a look at [flOSC](http://www.benchun.net/flosc/)
and for some reason serial data/usb make me think of arduino, make checkout [arduino2flash](http://protolab.pbworks.com/Arduino2Flash).

Can you explain what decive you're trying to get data from ?

Answer (score 2):

No. A web application cannot access user's machine without his permission. An SWF on your hard disk cannot read anything outside its folder.